# dymanic count query bind variable does not exist

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

i want to execute dynamic count for view employeesview
so i applied the current function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_num_of_employees
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_query_str VARCHAR2(1000);
  v_num_of_employees NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_query_str := 'select count(*) into :countresult  from employeesview'; 

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query_str
    USING out v_num_of_employees;
  RETURN v_num_of_employees;
END;
```

but when i execute this function

```
select get_num_of_employees from dual
```

iam getting the error 
01006. 00000 -  "bind variable does not exist"

is my function right or is there any other way to execute dynamic count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to run a dynamic `SELECT` query and save the result into a variable:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_num_of_employees
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_query_str VARCHAR2(1000);
  v_num_of_employees NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_query_str := 'select count(*) from employeesview'; 

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query_str
    into v_num_of_employees;
  RETURN v_num_of_employees;
END;
```

In this situation you don't need dynamic SQL, so I assume you need it in your real code for some reason.

If you don't have a good reason to use dynamic SQL, your function can be simplified:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_num_of_employees
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_num_of_employees NUMBER;
BEGIN
  select count(*) into v_num_of_employees from employeesview;
  RETURN v_num_of_employees;
END;
```

Comment: i know but suppose i need to execute dynamic and later i will append a dynamic filter in select query  why iam getting this error now

Answer (score 0):

thanks very much but i have solved it simply as following

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_num_of_employees
RETURN NUMBER
IS
  v_query_str VARCHAR2(1000);
  v_num_of_employees NUMBER;
BEGIN
  v_query_str := 'select count(*)  from employeesview'; 

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_query_str
    into v_num_of_employees ;
  RETURN v_num_of_employees;  
END;
```

and you can append any filter in the v_query_str or pass view name as parameter later to achieve real dynamic execution

Comment: ... that is exactly what I posted

Comment: thanks very much for your helpful answer may be i didn't read the whole answer carefully